# google fonts not loading in IE or edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, microsoft-edge

Have been reading around trying a few of the fixes mentioned on similar topics.

trying to use the lato font and its rendering fine on every browser apart from IE and edge.

I've been reading that IE doesn't use woff2?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), 
  url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v13/UyBMtLsHKBKXelqf4x7VRQ.woff2) 
    format('woff2');
 unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-
2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Lato';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'),           
   url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v13/1YwB1sO8YE1Lyjf12WNiUA.woff2)      
       format('woff2');
   unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC,                
   U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
 }
```

Comment: Why dont' you simply import the font via google fonts? It will already have all the stuff you need. Just use it via font-family where ever you need.

Comment: not working unfortunately, have added @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700'); to my CSS file and am calling font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; however it seems to direct to arial

Comment: any errors in console?

Answer (score 1):

You could import them using the `link` attribute like this:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  Iste officia in delectus asperiores recusandae deleniti natus. Quia consequuntur incidunt repellat quibusdam omnis maxime nostrum. Incidunt molestiae vero quibusdam tempore veniam. Quia et soluta beatae culpa inventore. Optio architecto tenetur atque et. Et voluptatum nam aut rerum qui deserunt.
Et odit deleniti dicta earum optio sunt maiores exercitationem. Repudiandae dolor aut et est. Veritatis dolor non et dolores. Necessitatibus rem perspiciatis molestias voluptate.
Sed vitae accusantium omnis delectus laborum iure et voluptatem. Commodi qui et atque delectus libero. Explicabo quo natus sed sed velit ut consequatur. Nesciunt illo quia excepturi vitae eius fugit. Id nobis pariatur porro hic. Sapiente dolores officiis et numquam labore sit placeat.
Voluptas suscipit molestiae quae quia molestias. Consequatur voluptas provident asperiores voluptatem consectetur soluta. Iste repellat cum tenetur eligendi esse assumenda explicabo numquam.
Et ut modi neque omnis. Quod et porro aspernatur dolores velit distinctio nisi et. Id eum sed perferendis illo repellat odit a fugit. Eligendi sed quasi cum. Eius inventore enim cum nulla repellat in molestiae corrupti. Qui tenetur vel et temporibus fugiat.
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, unfortunately cant add anything to the html

Comment: Okay...I just read your comment. It does work for me with @import though - on Edge and Chrome.